# How to print list of names in mail body using java mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using Java mail api to send emails.I have embedded an image in the mail body. It is appearing in mail body correctly. Now I am trying to add list of names in mail body, iterating this list & adding it to `StringBuilder`. I have appended new line between each name. In console when I print `StringBuilder`, it is printing each name in new line. But when I pass this builder as

```
StringBuilder emailContent;
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(emailContent, "text/html");
```

I am getting an `IOException`.

& when i am pass builder using toString() method, i am getting the names in same line.

Comment: Can you paste the exception stack trace. It will give more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaMail needs to know how to convert an object to the correct form for text/html content.  It knows how to do that for a String, but not for a StringBuilder.  Use emailContent.toString().

Inserting a newline in html content doesn't cause a line break in html output.  You need to insert an html break <br/> or something like that.